# Understanding Keras predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I've got the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import seed
from tensorflow import random

seed(42)
random.set_seed(43)

X = [
    'may it all be fine in the world',
    'this is not for me',
    'pffff ugly bike',
    'dropping by to say leave me alone',
    'getting sarcastic by now'
    'how would one satisfy his or her needs when the earth is boiling'
]

y = [1,2,4,5,3]

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = 13)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)
X_train_seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X)


X_train_seq_padded = pad_sequences(X_train_seq, maxlen = 15)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_dim = 15, activation = 'relu', name = 'hidden-1'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'relu', name = 'hidden-2'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'relu', name = 'hidden-3'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax', name = 'output_layer'))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

class CustomCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        print('finished an epoch')
        zin = 'dropping by to say leave her alone'
        zin = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(zin)
        zin = pad_sequences(zin, maxlen = 15)
        print(model.predict(zin))
        print(np.argmax(model.predict(zin), axis=-1))
callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor = 'accuracy', patience = 5, mode = 'max'), CustomCallback()]

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
encoder = LabelBinarizer()
y = encoder.fit_transform(y)

history = model.fit(X_train_seq_padded, y, epochs = 100, batch_size = 100, callbacks = callbacks)
```

I would expect that inside the callback `model.predict()` would result in something like (as there are 5 possible classes):

```
[0.4534534, 0.5634246, 0.0045623, 0.0004536, 0.0000056]
```

and `np.argmax(model.predict(zin), axis=-1)` in a single number 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5.

However the output I am receiving (showing one epoch) is:

[image]

How must I interpret this and how can I filter out the actual class the model would predict a sentence to be part of?

Comment: i think you are looking for something like this `# setup data to predict
X_test = ['may it all be fine in the world']
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_test)
X_test_seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_test)
X_test_seq_padded = pad_sequences(X_test_seq, maxlen = 15)` and then predict and display the result `my_labels = [1,2,4,5,3]
print(f"Prediction for {X_test} is {my_labels[np.argmax(model.predict(X_test_seq_padded))]}")`

Comment: Should I not use the same tokenizer on all the text?

Answer (score 1):

```
print(model.predict(zin)[0])
print(np.argmax(model.predict(zin)[0], axis=-1))
```

this should give you correct value.

tf models are designed to work in batches not as a single use so it gives you a list of outputs but because your input is a single item it just pushes that item n times through the NN hence the list of same outputs

Comment: How does it determine the amount of times it pushes the input through?

Comment: batch_size is one of the args, default is 32, try changing it to 1, see: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict

Comment: Does not seem to be caused by the batch_size. The `len()` of both is 34. Setting the batch_size does not have any effect.